# Recursive solution for detecting negatives?

Tags: c++, loops

I'm writing a program that detects the number of negatives in a stack. The first snippet of code below achieves the goal iteratively (I think). I'm trying to achieve the same goal recursively now. The second snippet is what I have so far.. However I am unable to make it successfully work.

```
int negcount = 0;
while(mystack.size() > 0) {
    if(mystack.top() < 0) {
        negcount++;
        }                   
 mystack.pop();
}
```

This is what I tried to make the function recursive.. There is definitely something wrong with the way the loop is setup but I'm not sure what..

```
size_t r_approach (stack<int> my_stack)
{   
    int cnt = 0;
    while (mystack.size() > 0) {
    if (mystack.top() >= 0) {   
        cout << " DO NOTHING" << endl;
        mystack.pop();
    } else {                
        cnt++;
        mystack.pop();
        r_approach(mystack);
    }                       
        }       
    cout << cnt << endl;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `r_approach(my_stack);`?

Comment: Looking at what you're trying to do here, are you sure `std::stack` is the right data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your solution pretends to be recursive, why the `while` loop? You are supposed to iterate using the recursion not the loop:

```
size_t r_approach (stack<int> & mystack, size_t count)
{   
    if(mystack.size() == 0) return count;
    int t = mystack.top();
    mystack.pop();
    return r_approach(mystack, count+(t<0));
}
```

Note that, in order to avoid copying the stack in each iteration, `mystack` parammeter is now passed as a reference. 
You may find strange that `count` is a parammeter too. That is to get tail recursion which is a good practice since some compilers can optimize the code.

**EDIT (To answer the OP comment)**

If you want to remove the extra parameter (count) and you don't need tail recursion, you just can keep the count using the return value:

```
size_t r_approach (stack<int> & mystack)
{   
    if(mystack.size() == 0) return 0;
    int t = mystack.top();
    mystack.pop();
    return (t<0)+r_approach(mystack);
}
```

Other option that would allow you to keep tail recursion is to wrap the initial implementation I gave you:

```
size_t r_approach_imp (stack<int> & mystack, size_t count)
{   
    if(mystack.size() == 0) return count;
    int t = mystack.top();
    mystack.pop();
    return r_approach_imp(mystack, count+(t<0));
}

size_t r_approach(stack<int> & mystack) 
{
    return r_approach_imp (mystack, 0);
}
```

Comment: You're solution works perfectly however I am curious about how I would make it work recursively without adding an extra parameter?

Comment: For my iterative approach, I was doing cout << negcount in the end which was giving me my answer. But in the top approach (r_approach), there is no output.. when I changed the last statement from return to cout, I got the following output "12356801235696023571212357281235744123576002357761235792023580812358240". I tested using a stack of size 11 with 7 negative numbers. Not sure why it is not working for me.

Comment: I'm adding numbers to the stack in my main function and then calling the function there.

Comment: @sparta93 You could just retreive the function result and print it: `size_t res = r_approach(mystack); cout << res << endl;` On the other hand, if you want a trace (observe the evolution of the count through the recursive call, just make `r_approach` print the value before returning it (last two `r_approach_imp` lines): `cout << count << endl; return r_approach_imp(mystack, count+(t<0));`